# Chrome VS Firefox img display compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have banners that display on the side of my site. Firefox and I.E. pull these up just fine however in chrome I don't get them at all. If I inspect the element I can see the  has the url of the image inside of it in chrome and in the resources it has the image but it just doesn't show up.

```
if (drBanner.Length > 0)
{
  for (int iRowIndex = 0; iRowIndex < drBanner.Length; iRowIndex++)
  {
    if (!CheckImageExist(drBanner[iRowIndex]["imgurl"].ToString()))
        continue;
    bannerValues += "{img class='right-banner' src='" + drBanner[iRowIndex]["imgurl"] +
                    "' onclick=MoveWindow('" + drBanner[iRowIndex]["imgnavurl"] + "') alt='" +
                    drBanner[iRowIndex]["imgalttxt"] + "'} $!$! " +
                    (drBanner[iRowIndex]["ovrimgimp"].ToString() == "0"
                        ? "1"
                        : drBanner[iRowIndex]["ovrimgimp"].ToString()) + "!~!~";
  }
}
```

The bannerValues result is as followed

{img class='right-banner' src='../Banners/oms_contactussidebar_oms_contactussidebar.jpg' onclick=MoveWindow('') alt=''} $!$! 1!~!~

the right banner class is also as followed

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    width:auto\9;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
```

Any thoughts?
EDIT 1:
This is the HTML as it appears in the inspection when on the page in chrome and FF.

```
<div style="height: 620px; width: 160px;" id="divBanner">
<img img="" class="right-banner"  src="../Banners/oms_orderingsidebar_oms_orderingsidebar_oms_orderingsidebar.jpg"   onclick="MoveWindow('')" alt=""> 
</div>
```

EDIT 2:

[image: When I inspect the element in Chrome 0x0 maybe that could be it but I don't see what's setting it]

Comment: -ms-interpolation-mode is an IE obsolete syntax

Comment: Even with that completely removed I still will not see it in chrome vs firefox and IE. 

Also if I inspect the page I can see that the -ms-interpolation-mode has been successfully removed. 

Version 37.0.2062.124 m That is the version of chrome I am using if that helps (should be the latest)

Comment: Why is `width:auto\9` ? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: Not 100% why they did that. This is code I am taking over for, last person isn't here anymore. 

I removed that however and still nothing in chrome but it appears just fine in IE and FF.

Comment: Edited post with html on the page when I inspect the page.

Comment: Alright I believe I found part of the issue. At least in Chrome. If I inspect the url of the image http://imgur.com/zKMsEzg

Comment: The HTML syntax is clearly wrong on the Edit2's image. Plus, you better set the image size with `height="628" width="157"` in the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your "image width" is set o "width:auto\9;" Try with "width: auto;" (without the \9). Other issue: "vertical-align" only works on "display: table-cell" elements, not on "display: inline" elements (img's).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not resolve the issue. I made sure in the inspection that these elements no longer appeared. FF,IE (good) Chrome (bad)